# MS Access VBA: Using variables to build Dim statements

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to build multiple Dim statements I have:

```
Dim p As String
Dim purch As String
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 0
Do While rst.EOF = False
counter = counter+1
p = "Purchase" & counter
purch = "Dim " & p & " As Purchase"
purch
rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

This throws a compile error: Expected Sub, Function or Property

The loop is building my command correctly but I can't get the command to run from the variable where it is stored.

Comment: Eh... What do you expect this to actually do? Do you move that variable later on? What's `As Purchase`?

Comment: As Purchase refers to a User Defined type.
    Type Purchase
        cardHolderID As String
        cardHolderName As String
        department As String
        statementDate As Date
        budgetCode As String
        transactionDate As Date
        vendor As String
        purchaseAmount As Currency
        requestedBy As String
        description As String
    End Type

Comment: `Dim` statements aren't executable. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Back up a few steps and explain what you're trying to do, overall.  You can redimension variables if necessary but I suspect that's not the case here either.

Comment: Looks like you need to learn about arrays and/or collections. Given that the number of iterations isn't known in advance, I'd go with a `Collection`.

Comment: Good call Mathieu - that's likely exactly what's going on.  @JohnRing take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/array.html) to see if this is related to what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have a dataset the has 370 columns per row.  An ID a name, a date, budgetCode1, transactionDate1, ...budgetCode60, transactionCode60

I am attempting to break up the row into a Purchase object for each budgetCode,

Comment: 370 columns is crazy, you need to normalize your data. What you have is a pivoted recordset... You want an object with a `TransactionCode` property, not an object with 300 `TransactionCode123` columns.

Comment: I wish I could normalize the data.  The table is populate by exporting the data from an eform so this is the only way it will let me build the table.  Each row has the possibility of having up to 60 budgetCodes with attributes tied to each budgetCode.  I am attempting to build a Purchase Object for each budgetCode in a row.   Example: Purchase1, Purchase2  each Purchase object will have attributes associated with the individual budgetCodes.

am I making sense yet?

Comment: You'll have to write the logic to un-pivot the data.. otherwise you'll go nuts! (I would!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code isn't a bunch of executable strings. You can't "execute" or "invoke" a string literal.

```
purch
```

Isn't a valid executable instruction, regardless of whether the value of that variable contains perfectly valid VBA code - as far as VBA is concerned, that's not code, that's a local variable, nothing more... the compiler is telling you that it doesn't know what to do with an instruction that does nothing.

> *I am attempting to break up the row into a Purchase object for each budgetCode*

You'll soon learn that a `Type` isn't an *object*, and won't play well with a `Collection`. Also, with 370 columns in a pivoted recordset, you're making your life much harder than it needs to be. If you mean to iterate budget codes, *make your query return the budget codes* and iterate *that*.

You'll need a *class module* - in its simplest form, it could be just a bunch of public fields:

```
'class PurchaseItem
Public ID As Long
Public Name As String
Public PurchaseDate As Date
Public BudgetCode As String
Public TransactionCode As String
'...
```

Now as you iterate your recordset, you create a `New PurchaseItem` every time, and `Add` it to a `Collection`:

```
Dim items As Collection
Set items = New Collection

Dim current As PurchaseItem
Do While Not rst.EOF
    Set current = New PurchaseItem
    current.ID = rst.Fields("ID").Value
    current.Name = rst.Fields("Name").Value
    current.PurchaseDate = rst.Fields("Date").Value
    current.BudgetCode = rst.Fields("BudgetCode").Value
    current.TransactionCode = rst.Fields("TransactionCode").Value
    '...
    items.Add current
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

And now you have all your items in the `items` collection.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm very much a VBA newb. I was not aware of collections.